# How to limit scanf while reading input from file

Tags: c

I'm a beginner with C and I have coded a program like :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {

    char r[10];
    char y[10];
    puts("Printing Data \n");
    while (scanf(" %10s %s",r,y) == 2) {
        printf("%s and %s\n",r,y);
}
    return 0;
}
```

CMD ./prog.c < file.txt

file.txt

```
aman dhaker
rudra pratap hensome
nitesh dhakar
```

While I wanted scanf to read just 2 strings but having 3 strings on line 2 of file.txt I wanted to skip the 3rd arg which was hensome as I only wish to print 2 strings but somehow I'm unable to skip particular string.

My current output :

```
aman dhaker
rudra pratap hensome
nitesh dhakar
```

My desired output:

```
aman dhaker
rudra pratap
nitesh dhakar
```

Please help me out.

I've tried including regex like [^ ] to exclude result including a whitespace but didn't work out.

Comment: attacker nine, What should happen if a line of input is only `"aman\n"`?

Answer (score 5):

You can read each line with `fgets`, and then apply `sscanf` to the string read, like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char r[10];
    char y[10];
    char input[100];
    while(fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin) != NULL) {
        if(sscanf(input, "%9s%9s", r, y) == 2) {
            printf("%s %s\n", r, y);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
aman dhaker
rudra pratap
nitesh dhakar
```

Note that I restricted the string length to `9` to allow for the `NUL` terminator.

Using `fgets` then `sscanf` is often better than using `scanf`. It makes the flow control much easier, and avoids having to clean out the input buffer - if there was a bad input you can just forget the string and input another.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you specify that you want only 2 strings in the `scanf` call, the other string remains in the buffer when you pass 3 strings, you need to flush/consume it:

```
while (scanf("%9s %9s", r, y) == 2) { // No need to use a space before first %10s
    int c;                            // and you need space for the NUL terminator
    while ((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    printf("%s and %s\n", r, y);
}
```

Comment: No need for a space before 2nd "%10s" either.

Comment: @chux, right, but IMO this makes more clear that you are scanning two strings